# Website not opening in webview on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone 8 App and I have a WebBrowser wich calls a local website containing a krpano.

The thing is, it doesn't show the panorama just a black screen, but when I call the same krpano but from an online server, the page displays as it should be.

Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 does not support flash player. You should consider using another technology rather than krpano.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but krpano currently supports HTML5 and CSS3, it should work right?

Comment: Maybe you should configure your krpano to use HTML5. I don't really know that tool.

Comment: I guess the problem is in running the javascript scripts, but I've already enabled javascript in the webBrowser.

Comment: I quickly checked krpano.com, and even if dev's are using HTML5, the core app is still an .swf file... So it's still flash...